# Excel, how to Sum on Column based on if the dates in another Column match the current month?

Tags: excel

I need to find the sum of the cells in a Column if their end dates in another column occur in the current month.

I tried using the formula `=sumif(L:L,MONTH(TODAY()),J:J)` but it doesn't work.

Column L contains the full date (ex: 12/1/18).

Column J contains the values I want to add up.

So since it's December, I want to add all the values in J that have a date that is in December, and so on a so forth when I use the sheet in January.

Comment: What does month(today()) evaluate to? Does it match what you are comparing it to in column J? if it doesn't, what do you need to do?

Comment: I need MONTH(TODAY()) to equal to the current Month, so for today it should equal December, but when I open and use this sheet again in January, it will equal January

Comment: Month(today()) evaluates to a number (12 when I tried it just now), but if you are comparing it to a full date 12/1/18 how do you expect it to match?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(L:L)=MONTH(TODAY()),J:J,0))
```

and enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> as it is an array formula.

Or use `=SUMPRODUCT((J:J)*(MONTH(L:L)=MONTH(TODAY())))`